# How to get part of string with Regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

this is my string: http://www.something.com/path/tt**0425235**/somethingelse/

and i need to get just "0425235"
(Beetween "tt" and "/")

Test with:http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and perfect ;)

```
<?php
$match = array();
$url = 'http://www.something.com/path/tt0425235/somethingelse/bla/bla/bla/bla/?bla=bla';
preg_match( '/\/path\/([a-z]+([\d]+))+\/?/i' , $url , $match );
print_r( $match );
?>
```

Bye!

Comment: Then try a slightly modified pattern instead: `'/\/tt(\d+)/i'`. The `$` was marking the end of the string so it didn't work for you, if you leave it out, this will get you the first number that follows `/tt`. It will be in `$match[1]` if found.

Comment: ok, guy, test now with this regexp /\/path\/([a-z]+([\d]+))+\/?/i

Answer (score 2):

```
#http://www\.imdb\.com/title/tt(\d+)/#
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.something.com/path/tt0425235/';

list($id) = preg_split('~^.*/tt(\d+)/$~', $url, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) + array(NULL);
```

If it can't find your pattern, `$id` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/http:\/\/[\w+-_\.]+\/path\/tt(\d+)\//
```

Or

```
~http://[\w+-_\.]+/path/tt(\d+)/~
```